# Subscribing to DOM Events Behind *ngIf

Tags: angular, rxjs

I like to be able to handle DOM events as an observable stream, calling filter, concatMap, etc. like the following example.

```js
@Component({
  template: `<button #btn>Submit<button`,
  selector: 'app-test',
})
class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  @ViewChild('btn') private btn: ElementRef<HtmlButtonElement>;

  constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(btn.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
      exhaustMap(() = > {
        return this.testService.save();
      }),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    ).subscribe();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

But sometimes the element I want to listen for events from is behind an *ngIf and doesn't exist when ngAfterViewInit runs. What's the best way to still listen for events in a reactive way?

One way I tried was to set up the same subscription as above in `ngOnViewChecked` behind an if statement that checked if the `ElementRef` exists, and with a flag to avoid multiple subscriptions. But I found that messy.

Is it a good practice to do something like this?

```js
@Component({
  template: `<button (click)="clickEvent.emit()">Submit<button`,
  selector: 'app-test',
})
class TestComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  clickEvent = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clickEvent.pipe(
      exhaustMap(() = > {
        return this.testService.save();
      }),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    ).subscribe();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

Should I replace the `EventEmitter` with a `Subject`? Is there a better way that any of these?

**edit:** just to be clear, my question has to do with subscribing to events from elements that might not exist due to an *ngIf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `@ngneat/until-destroy` you can do as follow

```
    npm install @ngneat/until-destroy
```

```js
    import { Component } from "@angular/core";
    import { Subject, of } from "rxjs";
    import { UntilDestroy, untilDestroyed } from "@ngneat/until-destroy";
    import { exhaustMap } from "rxjs/operators";  

    @UntilDestroy()
    @Component({
      template: `<button (click)="clickStream.next()">Submit</button>`,
      selector: 'app-test',
    })
    class TestComponent {

      clickStream = new Subject<void>();

      constructor(private testService: TestService) {

        this.clickStream.pipe(
          untilDestroyed(this),
          exhaustMap(() => {
            return this.testService.save();
          })
        ).subscribe();
      }
    }
```

for angular below version 9 you can use `ngx-take-until-destroy` mostly in same way

Comment: So would you say that setting up an Subject and then calling .next() in a (click) handler is the  optimal way to handle this? I'm not (for the sake of this question) concerned with the unsubscription mechanism, but this @ngneat/until-destroy looks pretty useful though.

Comment: @Dave yes with clickStream.next() you can not care about ngIf, other approaches looks too messy as for me

Comment: Could you explain why you used the asObservable() function first before piping through the rest of the operators?

Comment: @Dave it is redundant, i removed it. at first attempt i thinking to extract property for observable but leave it inlined

Answer (score 4):

Use `@ViewChildren` with a `QueryList` to listen to DOM changes.

```ts
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, fromEvent, of } from 'rxjs';
import { exhaustMap, takeUntil, switchMap, map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `<button #btn>Submit<button`
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  // Any time a child element is added, removed, or moved, 
  // the query list will be updated, and the changes observable 
  // of the query list will emit a new value.
  @ViewChildren('btn') private btn: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.btn.changes.pipe(
      // only emit if there is an element and map to the desired stream
      filter((list: QueryList<ElementRef>) => list.length > 0),
      switchMap((list: QueryList<ElementRef>) => fromEvent(list.first.nativeElement, 'click')),
      // add your other operators
      exhaustMap(() => this.testService.save()),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    ).subscribe(console.log);
    // Trigger a change event to emit the current state
    this.btn.notifyOnChanges()
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iklbs9

Comment: That's some fancy RxJS--pretty slick. Could you elaborate on why this is preferable to creating a Subject and then calling .next in a (click) handler?

Comment: @Dave I don't think there's an advantage in this case but it's generally more versatile as you get direct access to DOM elements, Components or Directives by using `ViewChild`/`ViewChildren`.

Comment: I like this solution a lot, but I can only accept one answer so I went for the simpler one. I could see myself using this solution at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first create a directive so that I can have access to the DOM element whose events I want to listen and also be notified when that directive is destroyed, so I can properly remove the listener when needed:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[notify-on-destroy]'
})
export class NotifyOnDestroyDirective {
  @Output()
  destroy = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(public elem: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnDestroy () {
    this.destroy.emit();
  }
}
```

And here's the component:

#### my-comp.component.html

```html
<button (click)="isShown = !isShown">toggle shown state</button>

<br><br><br>

<button 
  *ngIf="isShown" 
  notify-on-destroy 
>
  click me!
</button>
```

#### my-comp.component.ts

```js
isShown = false;

private eventSources = new Subject<Observable<any>>();

@ViewChild(NotifyOnDestroyDirective) 
set btn (v: NotifyOnDestroyDirective) {
  if (!v) {
    return;
  }

  const src$ = fromEvent(v.elem.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
    finalize(() => console.log('ev unsubscribed')),
    takeUntil(v.destroy)
  );

  this.eventSources.next(src$);
}

ngOnInit () {
  this.eventSources.pipe(
    mergeAll(),
  ).subscribe(() => console.log('event occurred'))
}
```

As you can see, I'm using a `Subject` whose values are observables. That's because I want to handle the observable's creation right in the setter.

`mergeAll()` will subscribe to all the incoming observables. With this approach, you can apply this logic to multiple elements as well.

[ng-run demo](https://ng-run.com/edit/FH2yw8oNihX0tyoWC3V9)